# Mouse event picker openscenegraph

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eventhandler, openscenegraph

I want to use OpenSceneGraph Pickhandler in order to print the name of a node when clicked on with a mouse. I have made a PickHandler Header file and included what I think is the correct code to make this happen.

After no errors upon running the application does not display the node name when clicked. Have I missed something important?

```
bool PickHandler::handle( const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter& ea, osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa )
{
  `if( ea.getEventType() != osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::RELEASE &&
  ea.getButton()    != osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON )
  {
return false;
  }

  osgViewer::View* viewer = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>( &aa );

  if( viewer )
  {
osgUtil::LineSegmentIntersector* intersector
    = new osgUtil::LineSegmentIntersector( osgUtil::Intersector::WINDOW, ea.getX(), ea.getY() );`if( ea.getEventType() != osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::RELEASE &&
  ea.getButton()    != osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON )
 {
return false;
}

osgViewer::View* viewer = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>( &aa );

if( viewer )
{
osgUtil::LineSegmentIntersector* intersector
    = new osgUtil::LineSegmentIntersector( osgUtil::Intersector::WINDOW, ea.getX(), ea.getY() );

osgUtil::IntersectionVisitor iv( intersector );

osg::Camera* camera = viewer->getCamera();
if( !camera )
  return false;

camera->accept( iv );

if( !intersector->containsIntersections() )
  return false;

auto intersections = intersector->getIntersections();

std::cout << "Got " << intersections.size() << " intersections:\n";

for( auto&& intersection : intersections )
  std::cout << "  - Local intersection point = " << intersection.localIntersectionPoint << "\n";
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you missed name printing in your code. Does it print the intersection size and the local intersection point as in the code?

Comment: Yes it prints the following information but not sure how to get the name of the node at that point.

Example of output:
Got 2 intersections:
  - Local intersection point = -0.148942 -0.512957 0.357376
  - Local intersection point = -0.159801 0.489366 0.363891

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract your node name in order to print it. If you do not use any custom nodes, then use `intersection.drawable->getName()`. Make sure you set up a name for that particular's `osg::Geometry`, otherwire the name is empty by default.

The printing code for your case would be something like:

```
for( auto&& intersection : intersections ) {
   std::cout << "  - Local intersection point = " << intersection.localIntersectionPoint << "\n";
   std::cout << "Intersection name = " << intersection.drawable->getName() << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However the last line of code errors explaining that the 'intersection' part is undefined. I don't understand this when the line of code above it works.
I have set up a nodeVisitor class which returns the names of nodes fine so would I just be able to use that?

Comment: @unistudent123 If you copied the code from my answer, I forgot to put an opening bracket `{` there. I edited my answer to fix it. Make sure the brackets are all right in your code.

Comment: I only copied - std::cout << "Intersection name = " << intersection.drawable->getName() << std::endl;
However intersection. is showing up underlined in red explaining ' identifier "intersection" is undefined. 
Confusing as the intersection.localIntersectionPoint works fine

Comment: Try to replace "Local intersection point" with the name code. The undefined identifier error should not occur, though.

Comment: That worked a treat! Thank you very much for your help Vicrucann